# Unit testing in typescript with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to unit test a typescript class with dependencies as follows:

****in collect.test.ts...****

```
import CollectAssets  from "../../src/collect/assets.collect";

  
it('works', async ()=>{

expect(await CollectAssets.collect().toBeTruthy()
  })
```

**in assets.collect.ts...**

```
import * as util from '../utils/utils';


const debug = util.debugGenerator('Collect assets')
export default class CollectAssets extends Collect {

    static async collect(
        pageContext: PageContext
    ): Promise<SA.Traces.CollectAssetsTraces | undefined> {}
```

**in utils.ts...**

```
import * as Debug from 'debug';

export function debugGenerator(namespace: string): Debug.IDebugger {
const debug = Debug(`${namespace}`);
return debug;
```

}

However when running jest it fails to run with the error:

> TypeError: util.debugGenerator is not a function

```
>  8 | const debug = util.debugGenerator('Transfer collect')
```

My tsconfig.json config file is :

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "rootDir": "./src",
  "outDir": "./build",
  "target": "es2016",
  "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution":"Node",
  "types": [
    "node",
    "jest"
  ],
  "strict": true,
  "inlineSourceMap": true,
  "noImplicitReturns":true,
  "declaration": true,
  "skipLibCheck":true,
},
"include": [
    "./src/**/*"
]
```

}

My package.json is :

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",

  },
      "jest": {
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
          "<rootDir>/test/config/setup.js"
        ],
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "testRegex": "/test/.*\\.test\\.ts$",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "ts",
          "js",
          "json"
        ]
      }
```

and I'm extending this in a jest ts config file:

```
{
"extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
"include": [
    "../../test/**/*"
]
```

}

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You omitted utils which is relevant.

Comment: @EstusFlask You are right. I have already edited that part.